# Amazon AWS tasks automation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a small EC2 instance constantly running and collecting data. We would like to have the ability to create another EC2 instance (bigger one .. more CPU and RAM) but with data from the smaller server. This bigger instance needs to be created on request and this task needs to be automated. Ideally, we would like to have a "single button" for this task.

I know that scripting this task is possible (using for example python CLI) but is there any tool or any AWS service that can help us to complete this task?

Comment: Anything is possible,  all depends on your desired workflow. IMHO, your workflow is ambiguous, so you may end up with many answers that may not suitable for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is **where to store the data so that it is accessible to both instances**. You should always try to store data in a database rather than a filesystem, which allows multiple instances to access the same data.

You then have a choice whether to launch a new 'big' instance, or whether to simply Start/Stop it as required. When an EC2 instance is stopped, there is no charge for EC2 (but you will still pay for disk storage).

As for launching another instance, it can be **launched from a script** using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). The script could launch the instance with a [User Data startup script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) that executes commands when the instance starts. This could load and run your application.

Once your instance has finished processing, it can **shutdown the virtual machine**. There is a **Shutdown Behavior** option that can either Stop or Terminate the EC2 instance.

You could also consider using [Amazon EC2 Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) for the second instance -- they can save substantial costs and the worst case is they get terminated and you can try again later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Lambda with [EC2 Python SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) to do this. To trigger the Lambda function, you can use different mechanisms. For example.

- Trigger Lambda by invoking a HTTP endpoint using AWS API Gateway
- Trigger Lambda by sending an email using AWS SES
- Trigger Lambda directly

Comment: or simply [invoking the lambda](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Updated the answer adding your suggestion. Thanks :)